# Return em laço while - PYTHON

Tags: python, while

Estou começando a aprender python agora e ainda estou perdido na sintaxe. No programa a seguir eu não sei o que fazer pra recomeçar o programa, ou seja, retornar ao inicio caso o usuário digite "sim" ou sair do programa caso o usuário digite "não". Alguém poderia me explicar como funciona essa função return em python?

```
"""
Escreva um programa que determine a pontuação do aluno.
A prova consta de 10 questões, cada uma com cinco alternativas (a, b, c, d, e).
O programa receberá os seguintes dados:
• o gabarito;
• as respostas do aluno, contendo o seu nome e suas respostas.
A partir daí o programa deverá comparar as respostas do aluno com a resposta do gabarito e, no final, exibir a pontuação do aluno.
O programa continua recebendo respostas de vários alunos até que o usuário informe que deseja parar de informar respostas de alunos.
"""

soma = 0
n = 0


while n < 10:
    print(f"Questão {n+1}:")
    gabarito = str(input("Digite o gabarito: "))
    nota = str(input("Digite a resposta do aluno: "))
    print("\n")
    n = n + 1
    if nota == gabarito:
        soma = soma + 1
print(f"A pontuação do aluno foi: {soma}")

resposta = str(input("Deseja continuar?\n" ))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bem, vamos lá.

While e for são laços de repetição, ou seja, executam uma parte do código "n" vezes, a diferença entre eles é que, o while você usa uma condição para manter a repetição ativa, enquanto no for você delimita quantas vezes ela deve acontecer.

Exemplo:

```py
x = 0
while x < 11:
    print(x)
    x += 1

for y in range(11):
    print(y)
```

Ambos os casos escrevem do 0 ao 10 na tela porém um usa o 'while' e o outro o 'for'.

---

O 'return' é utilizado dentro de 'funções' e serve para *retornar* um valor que está dentro da função para fora dela. Para declarar funções no python usamos do 'def'

Exemplo:

```
def soma(a, b):
    return a+b

print(soma(1, 2))
print(soma(4, 4))
print(soma(10, 1))
```

---

Existem várias maneiras de fazer o seu código ser executado mas de uma vez, uma delas ( sem função/return, seria colocar dentro de um while que verifica se o usuário deseja continuar. (Não é a mais 'linda' do mundo, mas funciona e fica simples)

Algo parecido com isso:

```
while (input("Deseja refazer? Sim / Não")) == "Sim":
    //Seu código vem aqui.
```